# inserted list changes even after being inserted

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array, append

I wanted to create a list of lists

```py
def func(m,n,l,t):
    a=[i for i in range(m)]
    b=[]
    b.append(a)

    a=swap(a)
    b.append(a)

    for i in b:
        print(i)

def swap(l):
    i,n=0,len(l)
    while(i<n):
        l[i],l[i+1]=l[i+1],l[i]
        i+=2
    return l
```

i created list **a** as my basis and append each modification i want to in the **b** list.
The problem is after i append the first list and modify it, the first one i inserted also changes the same as the second one i inserted.

the output of this code is this

```
[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
```

what i want is when i performm  the swap i dont want the first list to change

the output should look like this

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
```

if you could help, please thank you.

Comment: You never made a copy of the list `a`, so you're modifying it in place.

Comment: Use `b.append(a.copy())` or `a = swap(a.copy())`

Comment: Note: In Python, lists are always passed by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their are multiple code error you have done, for example:

you don't have to iterate over `range` object in order to get list, you could just...

```
a = list(range(m))
```

and also You don't have to run a `while` loop in order to iterate over two steps you could...

```
for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
```

see [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) for reference

also you didn't use any of `n, l, t` parameters of the `func` function.

**THE ANSWER**

when you pass the `a` variable to the `swap` function you are actually passing the class Object itself, so the `swap` function can change the value of the `a` variable (`list class`).

All you need is passing a copy of the `a` variable not the variable itself

```
a = swap(a.copy())
```

**FINAL CODE**

```
def swap(l):
    for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
        l[i],l[i+1]=l[i+1],l[i]
    return l

def func(m):
    a = list(range(m))
    b = [a]
    a = swap(a.copy())
    b.append(a)
    for i in b:
        print(i)

func(8) # [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of append() method, you can try out extend() method which does the same as of append. but extend() method is mainly used for iterate items, as of in your case.
and also if you want to use only append, then take a copy of your variable first and append it, as you are changing in the first place, it is taking effect in the list too. So you can follow append into a list like, **a.copy()**. Hopes it helps
Please try out and share the feedback.
Thank you

Comment: No. I think he really want list inside other list, he iterate over `b` and say nothing about lists printed.